# ilink64 Error Fatal: Error detected (EXE1829)

Tags: linker, c++builder

Error (ilink64) `Error Fatal: Error detected (EXE1829)` occurs during link of Win64/Release static library using C++ Builder 10.2.3.
Win64/Debug links fine as well as any Win32 version.

Library depends on other static libraries. I tried to clean all group project items and rebuild. I also tried to restart IDE. All without success.

Does anybody know, where to find information on what EXE1829 means or how to solve it? TY in advance for any reply.

Comment: "*where to find information on what EXE1829 means*" - information about linker error codes is generally not available to the public. You are going to have to contact Embarcadero Support directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau TY for your answer. The answer unfortunatelly corresponds to my observation so I blame Embarcadero for creating cryptic tool.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late but today I stumbled over the same linker error in BCB 10.2.3 when using a static lib in a package and trying to compile for 64bit.

The solution was to remove the `#pragma package(smart_init)` statement in the static lib itself.